# Chaining Scalaz validation functions: Function1[A,Validation[E,B]]

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm trying to write some code to make it easy to chain functions that return Scalaz `Validation` types.  One method I am trying to write is analogous to `Validation.flatMap` (Short circuit that validation) which I will call `andPipe`.  The other is analogous to `|@|` on `ApplicativeBuilder` (accumulating errors) except it only returns the final `Success` type, which I will call `andPass`

Suppose I have functions:

```
def allDigits: (String) => ValidationNEL[String, String]
def maxSizeOfTen: (String) => ValidationNEL[String, String] 
def toInt: (String) => ValidationNEL[String, Int]
```

As an example, I would like to first pass the input String to both allDigits and maxSizeOf10.  If there are failures, it should short circuit by not calling the toInt function and return either or both failures that occurred.  If Successful, I would like to pass the Success value to the toInt function.  From there, it would either Succeed with the output value being an Int, or it would fail returning only the validation failure from toInt.

```
def intInput: (String) => ValidationNEL[String,Int] = (allDigits andPass maxSizeOfTen) andPipe toInt
```

Is there a way to do this without my add-on implementation below?

Here is my Implementation:

```
  trait ValidationFuncPimp[E,A,B] {
    val f: (A) => Validation[E, B]

    /** If this validation passes, pass to f2, otherwise fail without accumulating. */
    def andPipe[C](f2: (B) => Validation[E,C]): (A) => Validation[E,C] = (a: A) => {
      f(a) match {
        case Success(x) => f2(x)
        case Failure(x) => Failure(x)
      }
    }

    /** Run this validation and the other validation, Success only if both are successful.  Fail accumulating errors. */
    def andPass[D](f2: (A) => Validation[E,D])(implicit S: Semigroup[E]): (A) => Validation[E,D] = (a:A) => {
      (f(a), f2(a)) match {
        case (Success(x), Success(y)) => Success(y)
        case (Failure(x), Success(y)) => Failure(x)
        case (Success(x), Failure(y)) => Failure(y)
        case (Failure(x), Failure(y)) => Failure(S.append(x, y))
      }
    }
  }
  implicit def toValidationFuncPimp[E,A,B](valFunc : (A) => Validation[E,B]): ValidationFuncPimp[E,A,B] = {
    new ValidationFuncPimp[E,A,B] {
      val f = valFunc
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass the success value from `allDigits` to `maxSizeOfTen` AND accumulate failures? Or, are you trying to call `allDigits`, `maxSizeOfTen`, `toInt` with the same input, accumulate failures and throw out all successes except `toInt`?

Comment: I have edited the 'As An Example' paragraph to make it more clear (hopefully).

Comment: Well, this is stupid.  I buried the implicit conversion in the trait so it couldn't find it.  However, the question still remains: is there a way to do this without this added code.

Comment: By added code, do you mean your Validation pimp?

Comment: Yes, without the Validation pimp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not claiming that this answer is necessarily any better than [drstevens's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13963136/334519), but it takes a slightly different approach and wouldn't fit in a comment there.

First for our validation methods (note that I've changed the type of `toInt` a bit, for reasons I'll explain below):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def allDigits: (String) => ValidationNEL[String, String] =
  s => if (s.forall(_.isDigit)) s.successNel else "Not all digits".failNel

def maxSizeOfTen: (String) => ValidationNEL[String, String] =
  s => if (s.size <= 10) s.successNel else "Too big".failNel

def toInt(s: String) = try(s.toInt.right) catch {
  case _: NumberFormatException => NonEmptyList("Still not an integer").left
}
```

I'll define a type alias for the sake of convenience:

```
type ErrorsOr[+A] = NonEmptyList[String] \/ A
```

Now we've just got a couple of Kleisli arrows:

```
val validator = Kleisli[ErrorsOr, String, String](
  allDigits.flatMap(x => maxSizeOfTen.map(x *> _)) andThen (_.disjunction)
)

val integerizer = Kleisli[ErrorsOr, String, Int](toInt)
```

Which we can compose:

```
val together = validator >>> integerizer
```

And use like this:

```
scala> together("aaa")
res0: ErrorsOr[Int] = -\/(NonEmptyList(Not all digits))

scala> together("12345678900")
res1: ErrorsOr[Int] = -\/(NonEmptyList(Too big))

scala> together("12345678900a")
res2: ErrorsOr[Int] = -\/(NonEmptyList(Not all digits, Too big))

scala> together("123456789")
res3: ErrorsOr[Int] = \/-(123456789)
```

Using `flatMap` on something that isn't monadic makes me a little uncomfortable, and combining our two `ValidationNEL` methods into a Kleisli arrow in the `\/` monad—which also serves as an appropriate model for our string-to-integer conversion—feels a little cleaner to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is relatively concise with little "added code". It is still sort of wonky though because it ignores the successful result of applying `allDigits`.

```
scala> val validated = for {
     |   x <- allDigits
     |   y <- maxSizeOfTen
     | } yield x *> y
validated: String => scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],String] = <function1>

scala> val validatedToInt = (str: String) => validated(str) flatMap(toInt)
validatedToInt: String => scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],Int] = <function1>

scala> validatedToInt("10")
res25: scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],Int] = Success(10)
```

Alternatively you could keep both of the outputs of `allDigits` and `maxSizeOfTen`.

```
val validated2 = for {
  x <- allDigits
  y <- maxSizeOfTen
} yield x <|*|> y
```

I'm curious if someone else could come up with a better way to combine these. It's not really composition...

```
val validatedToInt = (str: String) => validated2(str) flatMap(_ => toInt(str))
```

Both `validated` and `validated2` accumulate failures as shown below:

```
scala> def allDigits: (String) => ValidationNEL[String, String] = _ => failure(NonEmptyList("All Digits Fail"))
allDigits: String => scalaz.Scalaz.ValidationNEL[String,String]

scala> def maxSizeOfTen: (String) => ValidationNEL[String, String] = _ => failure(NonEmptyList("max > 10"))
maxSizeOfTen: String => scalaz.Scalaz.ValidationNEL[String,String]

scala> val validated = for {
     |   x <- allDigits
     |   y <- maxSizeOfTen
     | } yield x *> y
validated: String => scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],String] = <function1>

scala> val validated2 = for {
     |   x <- allDigits
     |   y <- maxSizeOfTen
     | } yield x <|*|> y
validated2: String => scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],(String, String)] = <function1>

scala> validated("ten")
res1: scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],String] = Failure(NonEmptyList(All Digits Fail, max > 10))

scala> validated2("ten")
res3: scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],(String, String)] = Failure(NonEmptyList(All Digits Fail, max > 10))
```

Comment: if you use a for comprehension to try to combine allDigits and maxSizeOfTen, then it will "fail fast" and not call maxSizeOfTen if allDigits fails.

Comment: @stew Actually the for comprehension here is calling `flatMap`/`map` on the `Function1` Functor, not the validations. There is no failing at all until the yield. See http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2010/12/case-study-of-cleaner-composition-of.html

Comment: Flag your answer, explain your situation ask for it to be converted back to a regular answer.  They are pretty good about doing that if it's legit.

Comment: +1, but see my answer for one approach (not necessarily better) to composition.

Comment: Where is `<|*|>` from?

Comment: @Daenyth `<|*|>` is from scalaz 6.x and was renamed to `tuple` in scalaz 7.x. It is provided by `scalaz.syntax.apply._` https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/ApplySyntax.scala

Answer (score 1):

Use ApplicativeBuilder with the first two, so that the errors accumulate, 
then flatMap `toInt`, so `toInt` only gets called if the first two succeed.

```
val validInt: String => ValidationNEL[String, Int] = 
  for {
    validStr <- (allDigits |@| maxSizeOfTen)((x,_) => x); 
    i <- toInt
  } yield(i)
```

Comment: You are ignoring `validStr`. If either `allDigits` or `maxSizeOfTen` fail, `toInt` will still be called and you will only yield the result of that. `allDigits`, `maxSizeOfTen` and `toInt` are `Function1`, not `Validation`. This is what makes this question interesting. Of course you could just create a `Function1` out of what you have, but I think the OP was trying to come up with a better way of composing these without manually passing what would be  the param to `validInt` to all of the other three functions.

Comment: Since we're dealing with (A) => Validation instead of Validation, this doesn't quite work. With a little modification, was able to produce this: gist.github.com/4347051

Comment: @OleTravel Yes, this was what I meant by "manually passing what would be the param to validInt to all of the other three functions."